# Webrtc video broadcasting Viewer only works sometimes

Tags: javascript, connection, webrtc, viewer, broadcasting

I´m using [Gabriel Tanners video broadcasting Tutorial](https://gabrieltanner.org/blog/webrtc-video-broadcast) on localhost it works great! Over Internet connection most of the times the viewer simply doesn't show anything. I spent hours testing and changing the lifecycle. Nothing works.

Here´s the Broadcaster code:

```
const peerConnections = {};
const config = {
  iceServers: [
    {
      urls: ["stun:stun.l.google.com:19302"]
    }
  ]
};

const socket = io.connect(window.location.origin);

socket.on("answer", (id, description) => {
  peerConnections[id].setRemoteDescription(description);
});

socket.on("watcher", id => {
  const peerConnection = new RTCPeerConnection(config);
  peerConnections[id] = peerConnection;

  let stream = videoElement.srcObject;
  stream.getTracks().forEach(track => peerConnection.addTrack(track, stream));

  peerConnection.onicecandidate = event => {
    if (event.candidate) {
      socket.emit("candidate", id, event.candidate);
    }
  };

  peerConnection
    .createOffer()
    .then(sdp => peerConnection.setLocalDescription(sdp))
    .then(() => {
      socket.emit("offer", id, peerConnection.localDescription);
    });
});

socket.on("candidate", (id, candidate) => {
  peerConnections[id].addIceCandidate(new RTCIceCandidate(candidate));
});

socket.on("disconnectPeer", id => {
  peerConnections[id].close();
  delete peerConnections[id];
});

window.onunload = window.onbeforeunload = () => {
  socket.close();
};

// Get camera and microphone
const videoElement = document.querySelector("video");
const audioSelect = document.querySelector("select#audioSource");
const videoSelect = document.querySelector("select#videoSource");

audioSelect.onchange = getStream;
videoSelect.onchange = getStream;

getStream()
  .then(getDevices)
  .then(gotDevices);

function getDevices() {
  return navigator.mediaDevices.enumerateDevices();
}

function gotDevices(deviceInfos) {
  window.deviceInfos = deviceInfos;
  for (const deviceInfo of deviceInfos) {
    const option = document.createElement("option");
    option.value = deviceInfo.deviceId;
    if (deviceInfo.kind === "audioinput") {
      option.text = deviceInfo.label || `Microphone ${audioSelect.length + 1}`;
      audioSelect.appendChild(option);
    } else if (deviceInfo.kind === "videoinput") {
      option.text = deviceInfo.label || `Camera ${videoSelect.length + 1}`;
      videoSelect.appendChild(option);
    }
  }
}

function getStream() {
  if (window.stream) {
    window.stream.getTracks().forEach(track => {
      track.stop();
    });
  }
  const audioSource = audioSelect.value;
  const videoSource = videoSelect.value;
  const constraints = {
    audio: { deviceId: audioSource ? { exact: audioSource } : undefined },
    video: { deviceId: videoSource ? { exact: videoSource } : undefined }
  };
  return navigator.mediaDevices
    .getUserMedia(constraints)
    .then(gotStream)
    .catch(handleError);
}

function gotStream(stream) {
  window.stream = stream;
  audioSelect.selectedIndex = [...audioSelect.options].findIndex(
    option => option.text === stream.getAudioTracks()[0].label
  );
  videoSelect.selectedIndex = [...videoSelect.options].findIndex(
    option => option.text === stream.getVideoTracks()[0].label
  );
  videoElement.srcObject = stream;
  socket.emit("broadcaster");
}

function handleError(error) {
  console.error("Error: ", error);
}
```

The viewer:

```
let peerConnection;
const config = {
  iceServers: [
    {
      urls: ["stun:stun.l.google.com:19302"]
    }
  ]
};

const socket = io.connect(window.location.origin);
const video = document.querySelector("video");

socket.on("offer", (id, description) => {
  peerConnection = new RTCPeerConnection(config);
  peerConnection
    .setRemoteDescription(description)
    .then(() => peerConnection.createAnswer())
    .then(sdp => peerConnection.setLocalDescription(sdp))
    .then(() => {
      socket.emit("answer", id, peerConnection.localDescription);
    });
  peerConnection.ontrack = event => {
    video.srcObject = event.streams[0];
  };
  peerConnection.onicecandidate = event => {
    if (event.candidate) {
      socket.emit("candidate", id, event.candidate);
    }
  };
});

socket.on("candidate", (id, candidate) => {
  peerConnection
    .addIceCandidate(new RTCIceCandidate(candidate))
    .catch(e => console.error(e));
});

socket.on("connect", () => {
  socket.emit("watcher");
});

socket.on("broadcaster", () => {
  socket.emit("watcher");
});

socket.on("disconnectPeer", () => {
  peerConnection.close();
});

window.onunload = window.onbeforeunload = () => {
  socket.close();
};
```

I´m very thankful for your help

Comment: Are you running over https, not just http. ?  Localhost works on http as it's deemed secure.  A lot of modern web APIs don't work unless using secure https.

Comment: I´ve tried both. I´m using ngrok for testing

Answer (score 1):

Since the two devices are not in the same network, you will need a TURN server for the establishment of the connection. A TURN server is used to relay as a relay if the peer-to-peer connection fails, which seems to be happening in your case.

Since there are no public TURN servers out there, you will probably need to create your own. For that, I can recommend the following options:

- [Coturn](https://github.com/coturn/coturn) - Has a lot of possible configuration options but is thereby harder to set up.
- [Pion TURN](https://github.com/pion/turn) - Easier to set up but doesn't feature as many possibilities

If you want to learn more about the internal of WebRTC and how they work together, checkout out [webrtcforthecurious](https://webrtcforthecurious.com/docs/03-connecting/).